# Do Minecraft Bedrock servers support multithreading?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

Do the bedrock edition Minecraft dedicated servers support multithreading?  According to the wiki, the client does, but I could not find anything about the server.

Comment: Is there some broader question you're hoping to find the answer to? For most people wanting to host a server, whether or not the server's threaded tends not to be relevant. That being said I believe there are operating system tools that could tell you the number of os threads a process so you could answer the question yourself by running the server and inspecting the process via these tools.

Comment: not just threaded, but capable of fully utilising more threads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Below is a screenshot of SysInternal's process explorer threads tab for the bedrock_server.exe process running on my machine.[image: Process Explorer Thread Count]

You can see a thread count of 25 threads. How much the bedrock server is optimized for multithreaded performance is another story. It's proprietary software so there isn't a way to verify that. Several factors besides threading affect performance. IO can be a big performance factor with Minecraft servers for instance.